# ngFor index reset to 0 when used with ngx-pagination

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of rawDataListDup | filter:searchText | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100,currentPage: q }; let idx = index">
<td>
  <select (change)="AssigneeChange(data,$event.target.value,idx)">
   <option [value]="data1.id" *ngFor="let data1 of groupList">{{ data1.name }}</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Consider `rawDataListDup` items as `300`. In above code `idx` value reset to 0, when ever I go to next page in table.

```js
AssigneeChange(data,id,idx){
  console.log(data,id,idx)
}
```

Consider the current index of `rawDataListDup` as `100`. In the console i get `idx = 0` instead of `idx = 100` when function `AssigneeChange` is called. This happens when i am in `page = 2` of table. In every page there will be 100 items.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [this](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#faq) for solution..

We can get absolute index using below code since paginate doesn't recognise it.

```js
AssigneeChange(data,id,idx){ 
idx = 100 * (this.q - 1) + idx;
console.log(data,id,idx)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of rawDataListDup 
   | filter:searchText 
   | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100,currentPage: q }; 
   let idx = index + paginate.currentPage  * paginate.itemsPerPage;
">
```

add to index the multiple between `pageSize` and `itemsPerPage`.

example:

```
page 0: item 0 = 0 + 0 * 10 = 0
page 0: item 1 = 1 + 0 * 10 = 1
page 1: item 0 = 0 + 1 * 10 = 10
page 1: item 1 = 1 + 1 * 10 = 11
```

Comment: `Parser Error: Unexpected token ; at column 161 in [let data of rawDataListDup | filter:searchText | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100,currentPage: q }; let idx = index + paginate.currentPage  * paginate.itemsPerPage;]`

Comment: try to remove `;` from the end

Comment: `Parser Error: Unexpected token +, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 114 in [let data of rawDataListDup | filter:searchText | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100,currentPage: q }; let idx = index + paginate.currentPage  * paginate.itemsPerPage]`

Answer (score 0):

pass "q" instead of "idx" to AssigneeChange function.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Using `indexOf()` method to get index of item in the loop.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of rawDataListDup | filter:searchText | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100,currentPage: q };>
  <td>
    <select (change)="AssigneeChange(data,$event.target.value, rawDataListDup.indexOf(data)">
      <option [value]="data1.id" *ngFor="let data1 of groupList">{{ data1.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```